# Oracle PLSQL: Performance issue when using TABLE functions

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql

I am currently facing a performance problem when using the table functions. I will explain.

I am working with Oracle types and one of them is defined like below:

```
create or replace TYPE TYPESTRUCTURE AS OBJECT 
    ( 
        ATTR1       VARCHAR2(30),
        ATTR2       VARCHAR2(20),
        ATTR3       VARCHAR2(20),
        ATTR4       VARCHAR2(20),
        ATTR5       VARCHAR2(20),
        ATTR6       VARCHAR2(20),
        ATTR7       VARCHAR2(20),
        ATTR8       VARCHAR2(20),
        ATTR9       VARCHAR2(20),
        ATTR10      VARCHAR2(20),
        ATTR11      VARCHAR2(20),
        ATTR12      VARCHAR2(20),
        ATTR13      VARCHAR2(10),
        ATTR14      VARCHAR2(50),
        ATTR15      VARCHAR2(13)
    );
```

Then I have one table of this type like:

```
create or replace TYPE TYPESTRUCTURE_ARRAY AS TABLE OF TYPESTRUCTURE ;
```

I have one procedure with the following variables:

```
  arr QCSTRUCTURE_ARRAY;
  arr2 QCSTRUCTURE_ARRAY;
```

ARR is only containing one single instance of TYPESTRUCTURE with all its attributes set to NULL except ATTR4 which is set to 'ABC'

ARR2 is completelly empty.

Here comes the part which is giving me the performance issue.

The purpose is to take some values from a view (depending on the value on ATTR4) and fill those in same or similar structure. So I do the following:

```
SELECT TYPESTRUCTURE(MV.A,null,null,MV.B,MV.C,MV.D,null,null,MV.E,null,null,MV.F,MV.F,MV.G,MV.H)
BULK COLLECT INTO arr2
FROM TABLE(arr) PARS
JOIN MYVIEW MV
ON MV.B = PARS.ATTR4;
```

The code here works correctly except for the fact that is taking 15 seconds to execute the query...

This query is filling into ARR around 20 instances of TYPESTRUCTURE (or rows).

It could look like there may be lots of data on the view. But what gets me strange is that if I change the query and I set something hardcoded like the one below then is completelly fast  (miliseconds)

```
 SELECT TYPESTRUCTURE(MV.A,null,null,MV.B,MV.C,MV.D,null,null,MV.E,null,null,MV.F,MV.F,MV.G,MV.H)
    BULK COLLECT INTO arr2
    FROM (SELECT 'ABC' ATTR4 FROM DUAL) PARS
    JOIN MYVIEW MV
    ON MV.B = PARS.ATTR4;
```

In this new query I am directly hardcoding the value but keeping the join in order to try to test something as much similar as the one above but without the TABLE() function..

So here my question....  Is it possible that this TABLE() function is creating such a big delay with only having one single record inside? I would like to know whether someone can give me some advice on what is wrong in my approach and whether there may be some other way to achieve...

Thanks!!

Comment: Just a view I created. 
It doesn't seem to have performance issues itself alone and also works fine whenever I use the "hardcoded" query (the second one I added) ....

Comment: it could have dramatic impact depending on the view query. in the second query optimizer knows excatly that there is one row in `pars`, in the first query it doesn't, and assumes that there are 8192 rows - hence 2 different executions plans are likely to happen.

Comment: please show two execution plans for these queries, and try adding hint `/*+cardinality(pars 1)*/` (after `SELECT`) to the first one for starters

Comment: Just a note, hint `cardinality` is not documented by Oracle, although it is a very usefull one!

Comment: Sorry but not that deep into Oracle (this development is like my first development on here :) )
How can I get this Execution plan? Im working with SQLDeveloper

Comment: http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_xplan.html dbms_xplan.display function. see an example there.or just hit F10 in sql dev. add colon before `arr` (`:arr`) before doing it for the first query.

Comment: Sorry again for the ignorance but the query contains a object type (arr) as a parameter in which I do apply the TABLE() function. So I am trying to generate the plan in the Stored procedure itself but i see that it is not valid for plsql...

So I dont really know how to register it on the execution plan. 
This is what I  am trying to do...

Comment: `create or replace PROCEDURE             EXECUTIONPLANS 
IS
  arr TYPESTRUCTURE_ARRAY;
BEGIN

  SELECT TYPESTRUCTURE(null,null,null,'ABC',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null)
  BULK COLLECT INTO arr
  FROM DUAL;
  
 EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  SELECT MV.ATTR1
  FROM TABLE(arr) PARS
  JOIN MYVIEW MV
  ON MV.B = PARS.ATTR1;

END EXECUTIONPLANS; `

Comment: you can do a statistic on the tables, it will optimize your plan and your execution,  begin  dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('YOUR_SCHEMA', 'YOUR_TABLE'); end;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is likely caused by a poor optimizer estimate for the number of rows returned by the `TABLE` function.  The `CARDINALITY` or `DYNAMIC_SAMPLING` hints may be the best way to solve the problem.

**Cardinality estimate**

Oracle gathers statistics on tables and indexes in order to estimate the cost of accessing those objects.  The most important estimate is how many rows will be returned by an object.  Procedural code does not have statistics, by default, and Oracle does not make any attempt to parse the code and estimate how many rows will be produced.  Whenever Oracle sees a procedural row source it uses a static number.  On my database, the number is 16360.  On most databases the estimate is 8192, as beherenow pointed out.

```
explain plan for
select * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3));

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => 'basic +rows'));

Plan hash value: 2234210431

--------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name | Rows  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |      | 16360 |
|   1 |  COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|      | 16360 |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Fix #1: `CARDINALITY` hint**

As beherenow suggested, the `CARDINALITY` hint can solve this problem by statically telling Oracle how many rows to estimate.

```
explain plan for
select /*+ cardinality(1) */ * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3));

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => 'basic +rows'));


Plan hash value: 2234210431

--------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name | Rows  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |      |     1 |
|   1 |  COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|      | 16360 |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Fix #2: `DYNAMIC_SAMPLING` hint**

A more "official" solution is to use the `DYNAMIC_SAMPLING` hint.  This hint tells Oracle to sample some data at run time before it builds the explain plan.  This adds some cost to building the explain plan, but it will return the true number of rows.  This may work much better if you don't know the number ahead of time.

```
explain plan for
select /*+ dynamic_sampling(2) */ * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3));

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => 'basic +rows'));


Plan hash value: 2234210431

--------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name | Rows  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |      |     3 |
|   1 |  COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|      |     3 |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

**But what's really slow?**

We don't know exactly was slow in your query.  But whenever things are slow it's usually best to focus on the worst cardinality estimate.  Row estimates are never perfect, but being off by several orders of magnitude can have a huge impact on an execution plan.  In the simplest case it may change an index range scan to a full table scan.

Comment: Hi Jon
Thanks a lot for your clear answer :) Now I understand more or less how to get the execution plan and it is getting many problems regarding the number of times it is trying to iterate the dynamic table.
I guess that the main problem may be on the view itself but unfortunatelly this view is not under my control as it is an interface for another schema which not having "power" and any modification would  have big cost.
So as seeing that this kind of query is not helpingg (due to interpreting many records when in reality only one is there)       (Adding the query in diff messages)

Comment: SELECT MV.*
FROM MYVIEW MV
JOIN TABLE(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('ABC')) STRUC
ON MV.B = STRUC.COLUMN_VALUE;

Comment: I even tried to put the value 'ABC' in a single table and joining it with the view and the performance was good.

SO i was thinking on whether there could be some way to interpret the real number of records into that table and then apply that to the view. If I can find something which would allow me not to get into the view it would be great. Otherwise that is my last chance :)

Comment: I think dynamic sampling may still help you.  If you can't put it inside the query, as described above, it can also be set at the session level.  For example, if the session can execute this before the query is executed: `alter session set optimizer_dynamic_sampling=4;`.  There are some other methods to correct cardinality estimates described [here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=427).

Comment: I tried that and didnt help to improve the performance of it :(
Finally the only thing I wass able to do is to store the content of my object into a table with a GUID and use that table in the join with the query instead of using table() function. After the query is used I am removing that value from that "temp" table.
Unfortunatelly with the small time I had to dedicate to this plus the delivery of my project had to deal with this workaround solution which at least has the performance i need :)
Looks the direction of the issue is with the dynamic sampling as you (Jon) stated.